# connection.closed is not a function SignalR

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm confused about the closed event in `SignalR`. Apparently, there was some debate about what to call it e.g. `onClosed()`, `closed()`, etc.

In my `SignalR` listener on the client side, I'm trying to implement this event but I keep getting an error that says it's not a function. I tried `onClosed()` and `closed()`. Same error. How do I detect the closed event on the client side?

```js
const signalRListener = () => {

   connection.on('new_message', message => {

      // Handle incoming message.
      // This is working fine.
   })

   connection.closed(e => {

       // Try to restart connection but I never get here to due error I'm receiving
   })

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's how I start my connection:

```js
export const signalRStart = (token) => {

    connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("/chat?access_token=" + token)
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
        .build();

    // Set connection time out
    connection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 30000;

    // Start connection
    connection.start();

    // Invoke listener
    signalRListener();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As a best practice, call `connection.start` after `connection.on` so your handlers are registered before any messages are received.

```js
export const signalRStart = (token) => {

    const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("/chat?access_token=" + token)
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
        .build();

    // Set connection time out
    connection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 30000;

    //register listeners

    //Registers a handler that will be invoked when the hub method with the specified method name is invoked.
    connection.on('new_message', message => {    
        // Handle incoming message.
        // This is working fine.
    });

    //Registers a handler that will be invoked when the connection is closed.
    connection.onclose(e => {
        // ...
    });

    // Start connection
    connection.start();

};
```

Reference [ASP.NET Core SignalR JavaScript client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-2.1#call-hub-methods-from-client)

Reference [SignalR JavaScript API - HubConnection class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@aspnet/signalr/hubconnection?view=signalr-js-latest)

Comment: Yes, this is the correct solution and it's working now. Correct event handler is `onclose()` NOT `onClosed()` or `onClose()`. Changed the order and now registering the handlers first. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Sam I included a link to the HubConnection API so you can see the available members.